# If else statement keeps looping infinetely

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int n){ //Aprēķina skaitļa faktoriali izsaucot pati sevi
    if(n > 1)
        return n*factorial(n - 1);
    else
        return 1;

}
int main(){
int ok;
do{


  int n;
    cout << "Enter a integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    int x=factorial(n);
    cout << "Factorial=" << x << endl;
    for(int a=1;(a+2)<(x/2+1);a++){ 

       if(a*(a+1)*(a+2)==x)
            cout << "Equals " << a << "*" << a+1 << "*" << a+2 << endl;
        else 
            cout<<"Cant be a multiplication of 3 numbers"<<endl;
    }

    cout << " Do you want to continue (1) or end (0)?" << endl;
    cin >> ok;
}
while (ok==1);
}
```

So hey I got this code where it has a factorial function and it checks if the factorial can be a multiplication of 3 consecutive numbers

```
for(int a=1;(a+2)<(x/2+1);a++){ 

           if(a*(a+1)*(a+2)==x)
                cout << "Equals " << a << "*" << a+1 << "*" << a+2 << endl;
            else 
                cout<<"Cant be a multiplication of 3 numbers"<<endl;
        }
```

I am running into a problem in this part now if I for example enter 8 it gives out the factorial 40320 and infinite spam of "Cant be a multiplication of 3 numbers", ALSO when I enter 1 or 2 it doesnt spam out "Cant be a multiplication of 3 numbers" it just gives out the factorial 1 or 2 
Thanks for help in advance!!

Comment: Terminology note: `if` and `else` don't loop.

Comment: Note that the test loop will iterate about fact(n)/2 times, which will be very many times!

Comment: Also, are you sure you have the problem understood correctly?  Factorials are by definition many multiplications, so for n >=4 the condition is always true.  There is no need for any iterative testing.

Comment: And, you will want to do a test on the input parameter.  For not very high values of n you will get an overflow on the multiplication when calculating the factorial.

Comment: @ThomasBitonti not every factorial is a product of **3** consecutive factors.

Comment: Be sure you check the range of 'n'.  Factorials grow VERY fast.  A uint64_t can contain F(20), but not F(21).  Do you know the size your "int n;" ?

Comment: Ah, ok, missed that.

Comment: Would it be more efficient to make a table of f(n) and of (m-1)*m*(m+1) and look for matches, rather than the iteratively test?  The range of either seems small for integer types which are supported by C++.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `break;` statement after:

```
cout<<"Cant be a multiplication of 3 numbers"<<endl;
```

I believe the issue with entering 1 or 2 is the math in:

```
int a=1;(a+2)<(x/2+1);a++;
```

Comment: Now if I enter 4 who's factorial can be a multiplication of three consecutive numbers it shows that it cant be

Comment: @MrLucky2243 Sounds like you have more than one problem. This is one of the many places creating a [mcve] can assist you.

Comment: That's because your math says "if(a*(a+1)*(a+2)==x)." A starts as 1; (1*(1+1)*(1+2)) = 6. Thus, your lowest number that it can find is 6. (At least, this appears to be the case after a quick glancing over of it).